# Enable autoplay in youtube embedded movie by jQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube, autoplay

I embedd youtube movies with the code below:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="840" height="470" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bag1gUxuU0g?wmode=transparent&amp;autoplay=0&amp;autohide=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

As you can see in src attribute there is a variable autoplay=0. I wrote two line script in jQuery which should set the autoplay variable to 1.

```
var title = $("iframe#ytplayer").attr("src");
title.replace("autoplay=0", "autoplay=1");
```

But it doesn't work. How can this be done properly?

Regards, 
David

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You aren't modifying the src attribute.

```
$("iframe#ytplayer").attr("src", $("iframe#ytplayer").attr("src").replace("autoplay=0", "autoplay=1"));
```

Comment: While this causes the iframe to reload, it does not make the video autoplay :( Not sure why.

Comment: @JonathonHill Did you managed to get it work ?