# I have popup in colorbox and cookie but its loade the video every time

Tags: jquery, youtube, colorbox, autoplay

I am using colorbox to set an cookie popup and it's fine for now. 
In the window I have a YouTube video and contact form fields.

The jQuery I use is ok but the problem start when I did an AutoPlay for the YouTube video/
it seems clearly that in the jQuery I call to the div id `subscribe` to show and be visible

but i want to know how to call a file or include file or how to disable the AutoPlay only if it's not the first time
thanks 
and I did look into question so if you know just let me know

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited777=true') == -1) {
    var fifteenDay6 = 1000*60*60*24*13;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDay6);
    document.cookie = "visited777=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
$.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
```

Answer (score 0):

just found the trick for that, by Paul Graffam in page
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772567/2007513
so insert this code and don't forget to give an id to the iframe!!!

Comment: @Dual (the editor), when fixing grammar, capitalization is a plus.