# Quill - Setting Video autoplay to false

Tags: jquery, quill

Am Adding a video using the Quill Editor. When I render it, the video automatically plays. Is it possible to turn off the auto play feature?

This is how quill stores the data and this is the piece of code that runs in full screen in the mobile web view

```
<iframe class="ql-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src=""></iframe><p><br></p>
```

Comment: Add HTML button (https://github.com/benwinding/quill-html-edit-button) , so that you can edit the HTML, then you can add set autostart="false"

Comment: This is a customer facing application and we need to set it programmatically. I tried setting the auto play to false on the iframe and that doesn't work either.

Comment: If it is customer facing application, then you may need to use text replacement (such as replacing autoplay with blank)

Comment: This is the data that get stored. I don't see an autoplay tag in there.

<iframe class="ql-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src=""></iframe><p><br></p>

Comment: likely that the ql-video is autostart / autoplay. Please remove this class by text replacement

Comment: Can you please edit your post to show some code for reference?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772567/3825777  You'll see code there that uses jQuery's attr() and replace() so solve a similar question about playing videos automatically.  See if you can create a runnable stack snippet to replace the correct attr for quill with a button.

Comment: @KenLee removing the class doesn't help either

Comment: @HarpalSingh added the snippet code